# How to save a html page with SSL signature of the page source?

Tags: php, ssl, ssl-certificate, digital-signature

I want to create a tool that allows users to capture and download web page snapshots and later allows anybody to verify if some snapshot is altered or not. I know that HTTPS protocol puts SSL signature to every data packet so the web browser can tell if the content of the web page really comes from that server and it is not altered. I need to get those raw data packets and signatures.
So where do I have to dig? I know PHP.

Comment: SSL/TLS doesn't sign the payload, it is used to verify that a client is connecting to the correct server. There's nothing from that that you could save to disk that you'd later be able to say "here's proof that I got this HTML from the server". However, there is something called [Signed Exchanges](https://web.dev/signed-exchanges/) that actually exists for this very reason, but a server needs to manually support it, or [turn it on in Cloudflare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/4411075595661-Automatic-Signed-Exchanges-SXGs-)

Comment: *"I know that HTTPS protocol puts SSL signature to every data packet so the web browser can tell if the content of the web page really comes from that server and it is not altered"* - it does not. Regarding *"comes from that server"* - that's handled by the certificate authentication in the TLS handshake. Regarding altering - the integrity check is a HMAC which uses a secret both known to client and server, so it cannot be used as a proof.